# amCharts time instead of data on chart tooltip

Tags: amcharts

I try to learn amCharts and now I stuck with changing tooltip format from date to datetime. There is jsfiddle what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/m1a45zur/2/  The tooltip label which I want to change from date to only time is in red circle in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo5pw.png)
I think that I should modify this part of code:

```
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bulletSize": 5,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "title": "red line",
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
    "valueField": "value",
    "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[value]]</span>"
```

but I can't find in documentation any options that can change this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the category tooltip by setting [`categoryBalloonDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#categoryBalloonDateFormat) in your `chartCursor`. For example:

```
"chartCursor": {
    // ....
    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN:SS",
    // ....
},
```

You can find more information about formatting dates [here](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/)

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1a45zur/4/)

On an unrelated note, you should remove the duplicate timestamps from your data as the duplicate data is breaking your chart.